# Writing a shell program in Unix to compile and run a COBOL file using the Open-Cobol a.k.a GnuCOBOL compiler

Tags: command-line, compiling, compiler

The two lines below are what I have for my UNIX shell.

```
cobc -free -x -o$(basename "$1" .exe) "$1"

./$(basename "$1" .exe)
```

When I type:

```
./myshell file.cob
```

...the program runs fine. But the original cobolfile (no extension) gets overwritten with compiled system code so the content looks exactly like the cobolfile.exe system code. So I can only run the program once then everything is lost... How to I tweak my shell program to avoid this?

Cheers!!  :)

Comment: You tried to change the `-o FILE_PATH` to some other location?

Answer (score 0):

The bash sample in the question seems to have been corrected - although it is quite strange to call an executable file ".exe" in a GNU/Linux system isn't it?

If you don't need the output file to be an executable I'd suggest to do

```
cobc -free $1
cobcrun $(basename "$1")
```